# ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Tags: java, android

Перестал работать `OnClickListener`, при клике пишет: `ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN` пробовала оборачивать Layout в другой,

```
<FrameLayout> <--- родительский Layout
<RelativeLayout> 
// содержание здесь 
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Так же пробовала к каждому элементу сделать свой onClickListener():

```
btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
```

Но все равно не работает. Что делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: попробуйте задать небольшой `padding` для Вашей `btnLocation`

Comment: Попробовала, не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `android:clickable="true"` для `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Попробовала, по прежнему не работает.